# Inherit class within the CSS

Tags: html, css, inheritance

Suppose in the CSS there are two classes  - `fatherDiv` and `childDiv`  -

```
.fatherDiv {
    /*
        With background and no special font color 
        */
    background-color: #b0c4de;
    width: 350px;
    height: 280px;
}

.childDiv {

    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

And want `.childDiv` to inherit all `.fatherDiv` style and add more .

The common way is to do  -

```
<div class="fatherDiv childDiv">I'm the Child</div>
```

But my question is  -

Does it have an option to inherit class style to another class within the CSS file ?

I tried  -

**style.css -**

```
.fatherDiv .childDiv {
    /*
          Inherit from .fatherDiv ...  
            */
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

**index.html -**

```
<div class="childDiv">I'm the Child</div>
```

[Here is its jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9rhDd/3/)

But it discard the interitance .

Comment: your query is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
.fatherDiv, .childDiv {
    background-color: #b0c4de;
    width: 350px;
    height: 280px;
}

.childDiv
{
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/9rhDd/6/

You may also do not call these elements `child` and `father`. They are siblings.

Answer (score 2):

Check this -http://jsfiddle.net/9rhDd/7/

```
 .fatherDiv,.childDiv {
    /*
        With background and no special font color 
        */
    background-color:#b0c4de;
    width:350px;
    height:280px;
    /*font-size:50px;*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
.fatherDiv {
    background-color: #b0c4de;
    width: 350px;
    height: 280px;
}

.childDiv {
    background-color:inherit;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

would work in theory as long as your HTML is like:

```
<div class="fatherDiv">
   <div class="childDiv"></div>
</div>
```

although `inherit` isn't valid on all CSS values so you would have to check that.

It won't automatically inherit the values, you would need a pre-processor like Sass to be able to do that.